# how i change background for all activity android

Tags: android

I put an image for all activity in my application (in style.xml ...). how I can change the background for all my activity dynamically. is it possible to change the properties of a  theme dynamically?

thank you for your help

Comment: You can do that from programmatically..in each and every activity  you need to set background in if condition using on Boolean(flag) value. if you change the background jst change the Boolean(flag) value..and if u navigate to the next activity..it will change the background based on Boolean(flag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change window's background in your activity using

```
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(...);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(...);
```

See [Window](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) docs.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. but getwindow for change the background of the current activity, how can I change the background of all activity
pleas help

Comment: seems like to achive it is to have only one activity, there is no way to change background of all activities at once either to have predefined themes

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can set the Background on each Activity XML Layout..

android:background="@drawable/bg"